# Linux console - start process and wait until finished

Tags: linux, process, console

I have to write console app which starts another process (GUI). Then with other app or option of the same I have to be able to stop the child process. In addition, if the child process is closed from GUI, I have to be informed to do final tasks (same if killed).

I suppose it is good to keep first (parent) app running while child (GUI) is working and continue with final tasks. For example in .Net this is made with Process.WaitForExit() after Process.Start().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read **wait(2)** and **exit(2)** system calls manpages.  **wait(2)** stops the calling process until some of it's children has **exit(2)** and **exit(2)** just do the reciprocal, exits the program and lets the kernel inform its parent process of that, passing it the exit code supplied.